# Node.js Stripe Connect implementation with already created users on my platform

Tags: javascript, node.js, stripe-payments

I am trying to add Stripe Connect to my app, but I do not want to create users using Stripe Connect integration. I have my own user sign up process, because not every user will need the payment option provided by Stripe so I do not want to force everyone signing up to Stripe if they do not need it. That is where my problem is. I follow Stripe's quite nice and straight forward documentation here: (https://stripe.com/docs/connect/enable-payment-acceptance-guide).

My problem is that I do not know how to save the user's stripe_account_id which the oauth return s to the /connect/oauth path so it is saved to appropriate user since there is no id of the user passed. How can I find out, which user is connecting to Stripe and save the id to his account in database? I feel like I am missing something here. I understand this would work if I would create a user but I cannot do it that way.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create the OAuth link that connects your users to your platform, you can pass in an arbitrary `state` string [which Stripe will then pass back to you](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/oauth-reference#get-authorize-request) after the link is completed. If you put your user's unique ID in there, you'll be able to link the completed connection back to your user in your database.

Comment: Thank you. That is what I was thinking to do and tried to do. But at the same time I was wondering whether that is the correct approach since the state is only optional parameter. I would imagine functionality like that should be achieved by the required parameters out of the box maybe passing the jwt token along the route.

Comment: It works this way, I am just unsure if it the safest and kosher way of doing it. Since money are involved, I would not want to make some mistake.